# Compare large print machzorim

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, see-sight-vision-blind

My husband is recently visually impaired with a condition called NAION.  He has been using the Artscroll large print siddur on Shabbat and a siddur app on his phone for weekdays.  I want to get him Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur machzorim and am wondering if anyone has compared the large print 
Artscroll and Jewish Heritage for the Blind machzorim for font-size, readability, convenience, etc.

Thank you and shana tova.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Meira and thanks for this first question. I hope you get good answers that will help your husband. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Thank you mbloch.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with this vision condition. However, here are my thoughts on each of the two Machzorim.

The Jewish Heritage Machzor, I'm not sure contains everything. It has been a while since I last viewed it. However, the print is large. If I recall, it is spiral bound, which is a huge advantage in that it can lie flat. It also is much lighter than the Art Scroll one.

The Art Scroll is thorough and has large font. However, if I recall, it tends to use gray shading for certain prayers. I know that reason alone was why when my shul tried to convert their year-round Siddurim to Art Scroll, the older congregants protested, so we didn't use it. We do use Art Scroll (regular size) machzorim for High Holidays. I use the large print one as I am Shaliach Tzibbur. It definitely is missing some English translation of some prayers, and it is a bit heavy. (I have a slight problem coordinating my page numbers with the rest of the congregation, as the organization is different in the large print. But, I know Hebrew well enough to figure it out. However, if following along is a concern, this may be an issue for you.)

So, there are advantages / disadvantages to one Machzor over the other. Hope this helps you decide. Shanah Tovah.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thoughtful reply.  Art Scroll's large print versions for the visually impaired are different than the shaliach tzibur versions, I believe.  For example, my husband's A.S. Shabbat siddur has no grayed-out areas.  I will share your comments with my husband.  I'm keeping the question open in case anyone has seen the Jewish Heritage Machzor more recently.